# configuring an ubuntu vps to forward packets to two different servers

Tags: networking, iptables

I have three separate ubuntu VPS servers (A, B, C)
previously I only had one IP address associated with server A and used `iptables` to forward any incoming packets to IP `11.22.33.44` on port 443 to ip address `55.66.77.88` (server B)
and using server A as a gateway for my TCP connection to bypass the blocking in the client's region

I did that by adding a rule to `PREROUTIN` using the command below:

`$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 55.66.77.88:443`

as well as adding a rule to `POSTROUTING` :

`$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

I want to purchase another IP address (`99.10.11.12`) from my VPS provider on server A which would be connected to `eth1` and forward packets on that address to server C (`13.14.15.16`)
[image]

but as soon as the second IP is purchased and active, everything stops working even the packets incoming to `11.22.33.44` don't get to server B.

I'm not sure how to config the rules to get what I want and trying to learn about `iptables` only confused me even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a server has two or more network interfaces, asymmetric routing can be a problem. For example, a packet can come through `eth0` on `server A` and get forwarded to `server B`. When the return packet comes back from `server B` to `server A`, it might attempt to escape through `eth1` to the internet because that is where the default gateway is pointing to (or vise versa)

In this example `server A` will be configured with four interfaces:

```
eth0 - 1.0.0.1 (WAN-1 facing)
eth1 - 1.1.1.1 (WAN-2 facing)
eth2 - 10.2.2.1/24 (LAN-B facing)
eth3 - 10.3.3.1/24 (LAN-C facing)
```

`Server B` will have an IP of `10.2.2.2/24` with a default gateway pointing to server A's eth2 interface (10.2.2.1)

`Server C` will have an IP of `10.3.3.2/24` with a default gateway pointing to server A's eth3 interface (10.3.3.1)

Since `server A` has four IP addresses and there can only be one default gateway at a time else you might run into asymmetric routing issues.

On `server A`, you can execute the following commands to control the traffic

Traffic coming through eth2 (LAN-B facing) must be translated to eth0's public IP (1.0.0.1)

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -s 10.2.2.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 1.0.0.1
```

Traffic coming through eth3 (LAN-C facing) must be translated to eth1's public IP (1.1.1.1) on its way to the internet

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth3 -s 10.3.3.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.1
```